# Convert rows to column in oracle 10g

Tags: oracle10g, rows, transpose

I want to convert rows to column in oracle 10g using JOIN. I do not want to use DECODE or XMLAGG function. My table structure is the followings:

```
GROUP_ID    ENTITYID    GROUP_ENTITYID
1           A997        A995
2           A997        A993
3           A997        A990
4           A988        A987
5           A988        A982
6           A988        A980
7           A979        A975
8           A979        A974
9           A979        A973
```

I want to get data in following format:

```
ENTITYID    GROUP_ENTITYID

A979    A979,A975,A974,A973
A988    A988,A987,A982,A980
A997    A997,A995,A993,A990
```

Can you guys please advice me how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Tim Hall has the canonical listing of the various [string aggregation techniques available in Oracle](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php).

Using a join to combine the data would be neither practical nor efficient.  If you happen to know that `EntityID` will map to exactly three other `Group_EntityID` values, you could use a join

```
SELECT a.entity_id, 
       a.entity_id || ','  ||
         a.group_entityID || ',' ||
         b.group_entityID || ',' ||
         c.group_entityID
  FROM table_name a,
       table_name b,
       table_name c
 WHERE a.entityID = b.entityID
   AND a.entityID = c.entityID
   AND a.group_entityID > b.group_entityID
   AND b.group_entityID > c.group_entityID
```

But that approach is neither particularly efficient nor particularly flexible if the number of `Group_EntityID` values associated with a particular `EntityID` changes.

I would generally prefer creating the user-defined aggregate function (one of the options in Tim's listing) and doing something like

```
SELECT entityID, entityID || ',' || string_agg( group_entity_id )
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY entityID;
```

If you want to do it without creating any additional objects or functions, you can use the `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` approach on Tim's site

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with x as (
  2    select 1 group_id, 'A997' entityID, 'A995' group_entityID from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'A997', 'A993' from dual union all
  4    select 3, 'A997', 'A990' from dual union all
  5    select 4, 'A998', 'A987' from dual union all
  6    select 5, 'A998', 'A982' from dual union all
  7    select 6, 'A998', 'A980' from dual union all
  8    select 7, 'A979', 'A975' from dual union all
  9    select 8, 'A979', 'A974' from dual union all
 10    select 9, 'A979', 'A973' from dual
 11  )
 12  select entityID,
 13         entityID || ',' ||
 14           ltrim( max( sys_connect_by_path( group_entityID, ','))
 15                     keep(dense_rank last order by group_id),
 16                  ',') group_entityID
 17    from (select group_id,
 18                 entityID,
 19                 group_entityID,
 20                 row_number() over (partition by entityID
 21                                        order by group_id) curr,
 22                 row_number() over (partition by entityID
 23                                        order by group_id) - 1 prev
 24            from x)
 25   group by entityID
 26  connect by prev = PRIOR curr
 27      and entityID = PRIOR entityID
 28*  start with curr = 1
SQL> /

ENTI GROUP_ENTITYID
---- ------------------------------
A979 A979,A975,A974,A973
A997 A997,A995,A993,A990
A998 A998,A987,A982,A980
```

Comment: hi Justin,

Thanks for your reply. 

Your query will not help me. Because as you have already guessed the number of Group_EntityID values associated with a particular EntityID will vary.

Actually I was looking to use XMLAGG function. But I am not very much sure about this function. Will this function be available in any kind of environment? Does it need any component to be installed which may not be installed in different environment?

Comment: @SomnathGuha - Neither of the two queries I posted help?  Did you look at the other string aggregation techniques on Tim's page?  Do none of them work for you?  Can you explain why they don't work?  I suppose in theory you could use `XMLAGG` but that would seem rather more complicated than the alternatives for no obvious gain unless you really like generating and parsing XML.

Comment: @Juntin I have tried both the queries. First query is not usefull for me because there could be n number of group_entityid for a particular entityid. But your query only return 3 group_entityid. For the next query it is showing me string_agg invalid function error messgae. I have gone through Tim's solution. I believe that will work for me. But I was looking to solve this issue only using a sql query

Comment: @SomnathGuha - If you want to use the user-defined aggregate function, you'd need to define the function (as Tim does on his page).  If you want it to be a single query without creating any additional objects or functions, you can use the ROW_NUMBER and SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH approach Tim defined (http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php#row_number).

Comment: does SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH  requires any special permission or it is available to all types of user?

Comment: @SomnathGuha - It should be generally available to any user.